# On differentiation with respect to functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions, derivatives

When I have some product of two functions, such as: $$g(x)*f(x),$$

I can take the derivative with respect to $f(x)$, which by the chain rule, yields

$$\frac{\partial [g(x)*f(x)]}{\partial f(x)} = \frac{\partial g(x)}{\partial x} \cdot \frac{1}{f'(x)} = \frac{g'(x)}{f'(x)}.$$

If $f(x)$ were treated like a fixed variable $u$ instead of a function, we can express

$$g(x)*u \rightarrow \frac{\partial [g(x)*u]}{\partial u} = g(x)$$

What is the difference between the two? Would it ever be appropriate to use the second method and treat it as a variable instead of a function? What would the interpretation of the second method be?

Comment: Not clear. Are you taking derivative of $f(x)g(x)$ or $g(x)$? $\frac{{\mathrm d}g(x)}{{\mathrm d}f(x)}=g(x)$ doesn't make sense whatsoever. I assume you mean to say $\frac{{\mathrm d}[g(x)f(x)]}{{\mathrm d}f(x)}=g(x)$ instead.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Does my update clarify things?

Comment: Yes, it is much clearer now.

Comment: $f(x)$ depends on $x$. When you treat $f(x)$ as a variable,  $x$ is not independent anymore, and $g(x)$ becomes $g(f^{-1}(u))$.

Comment: What is the *definition* of derivative with respect to a function?